Isomorphism in Banach Spaces

Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces. Let $T: E \rightarrow F$ be an isomorphism (i.e., a continuous vector space isomorphism with a continuous inverse). Let $J_E$ and $J_F$ be the canonical injections of $E$ and $F$, respectively. Define
$S: E^{\star\star}/J_E(E)$ $\rightarrow$ $F^{\star \star}/J_F(F)$, $\quad$$[\phi] \mapsto\left[T^{**} \phi\right]$
a) Prove that $S$ is well-defined.
b) Prove that $S$ is a vector space isomorphism.
c) Prove that $S$ is continuous. Is the inverse continuous?
d) Prove that if $T$ is an isometry, then $S$ is also.

I'm trying to do this exercise but I have no idea how to prove that S is an isomorphism. I searched this forum and couldn't find anything like it. And for question C) my answer would be yes as a corollary of the open mapping theorem. For D) I have no idea.
I have attached the full exercise for more context.

Intenté traducir tu pregunta al inglés lo mejor que pude. En el futuro, tenga en cuenta que MSE es un foro en inglés.

Para la pregunta a), es suficiente mostrar que el mapa $\tilde S:E^{} \to F^{}/J_F(F)$ dado por $\phi\mapsto [T^{* *}\phi]$ es tal que $J_E(E) \subset \ker(\tilde S)$. Es decir, por cada $\phi \in J_E(E)$, $[T^{**}\phi] = 0$.

Para la pregunta b), debes demostrar que $S$ es inyectivo y sobreyectivo. Para la inyectividad, basta con demostrar que $\ker(\tilde S) \subset J_E(E)$. Es decir, si $[T^{}\phi] = 0$, entonces $\phi \in J_E(E)$. Para la sobreyectividad, creo que puedes demostrar que $[T^{}(T^{-1})^{**}\psi] = [\psi]$.

@BenGrossmann could you please speak in english?

@BenGrossmann do you have idea to prove or disprove C)? Or a idea for D)?

@Mathslover Translation: for part a), it's enough to show that the map $\tilde S:E^{} \to F^{}/J_F(F)$ given by $\phi \mapsto [T^{}\phi]$ is such that $J_E(E) \subset \ker(\tilde S)$. That is, for each $\phi \in J_E(E), [T^{}\phi] = 0$. For part b, you should show that $S$ is injective and surjective. For injectivity, it's enough to show that $\ker(\tilde S) \subset J_E(E)$. That is to say, if $[T^{}\phi]= 0$, then $\phi \in J_E(E)$. For surjectivity, I think you can show that $[T^{}(T^{-1})^{**}\psi] = [\psi]$.

@JasonJacob Your answer for C) seems fine; quotient spaces are Banach spaces after all. For D), I think the problem should be straightforward but you need to carefully use the definition of the norm that a Banach space induces on its quotient.

@BenGrossmann But the banach space isnt properly defined here right. You cant prove its injectivity

@Mathslover Why the Banach space isn't properly defined here right?

@BenGrossmann Could you give me an idea how to test D)? I haven't been able to achieve it yet. Also, I don't understand why you define an operator $S$ and try to prove that $J_E(E) \subseteq ker(S)$

A useful result is that if $\phi\in E^{**}$ and $g\in F^{*}$, then $(T^{**}(\phi ))(g) = \phi (g\circ T)$. This can be shown from the definition of the adjoint and can be applied over and over again in this question.
To expand on what was mentioned in the comments and summarise it in one place, for part (a), you can consider the map $\tilde{S}:E^{**} \to F^{**} / J_{F}(F)$ defined by $\tilde{S}(\phi ) := [T^{**}(\phi )]$. This is automatically well-defined. If you show that $J_{E}(E) \subseteq \text{ker}(\tilde{S})$, then you have that the map $S$ is well-defined because $\tilde{S}(\phi_{1}) = \tilde{S}(\phi_{2})$ whenever $\phi_{1} \in [\phi_{2}]$, so that the value of $S$ under an equivalence class does not depend on the chosen representative of that equivalence class. To do this, you want to show that if $\phi \in J_{E}(E)$, then $T^{**}(\phi )\in J_{F}(F)$.
For part (b), you want to show that $S$ is injective and surjective. To show that $T$ is injective, as mentioned in the comments, it is equivalent to showing that $\text{ker}(\tilde{S}) \subseteq J_{E}(E)$. To do this, you can take $\phi \in E^{**}$ such that $T^{**}(\phi ) \in J_{F}(F)$ and conclude that there is some $y\in F$ such that $J_{F}(y) = T^{**}(\phi )$. To show that $S$ is surjective, you want to take $\varphi \in F^{**}$ and show that there is some $\phi\in E^{**}$ such that $T^{**}(\phi ) = \varphi$. Then it follows that $S([\phi ]) = [\varphi ]$. Something that is useful for this question is that if $f\in E^{*}$ and $g\in F^{*}$, then $f\circ T^{-1} \in F^{*}$ and $g\circ T \in E^{*}$. In particular, for part (b) given $\varphi \in F^{**}$, you can define $\phi \in E^{**}$ by $\phi (g) := \varphi (g \circ T^{-1})$ and can verify that $T^{**}(\phi ) = \varphi$.
For part (c), you want to first of all show that if $\phi \in E^{**}$, then $\| T^{**}(\phi) \| \leq \|T\| \|\phi\|$. From this, you can conclude that if $\phi \in E^{**}$ with $\|\phi \| < 1$, then $\|S([\phi ])\| \leq \|T\|$. As every element of $E^{**} / J_{E}(E)$ with norm strictly less than one is of the form $[\phi ]$ for some $\phi \in E^{**}$ with $\|\phi \| < 1$, it follows that $S$ is bounded and $\|S \| \leq \|T\|$. You can either apply an analogous argument to conclude that $\|S^{-1}\| \leq \|T^{-1}\|$, or you can apply the bounded inverse theorem as both $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces to conclude that $S^{-1}$ is bounded. I will suggest showing that $\|S^{-1}\| \leq \|T^{-1}\|$, as it is more useful for part (d).
For part (d), if $T$ is an isometry, then $\|T\| = 1$ and $\|T^{-1}\| = 1$. So it follows from part (c) that $\|S\| \leq 1$ and $\|S^{-1}\| \leq 1$. It follow almost directly that $S$ is an isometry.
